# Eclipse conditional debug

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm wondering if there is a way to add a conditional break point in eclipse while debuging.
Sample: if city=="New York" then break.

Comment: You can also do this by opening `Debug perspective` --> go to Breakpoints tab and select your breakpoint. Then select the condition; here you can enter a new condition or use one of previous conditions. You can also use `ctrl+space` to get the content assist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Right-click on the breakpoint, select "Breakpoint properties", enable "Conditional" and then enter the condition. Note that `city == "New York"` wouldn't be a good condition due to the way equality works in Java, but `"New York".equals(city)` would be fine. Note that Eclipse allows simple Boolean conditions like this, and also "suspend when value changes".

Answer (score 4):

Here is the detailed tutorials.
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F

Answer (score 2):

Open the context menu over a break point on the left bar of the code editor, select "Breakppoint properties..." and "Enable condition"